# enabling discrete gpu and choosing which gpu to use

Tags: drivers, nvidia, gpu, xserver, nvidia-prime

Hi all since this is my first post here.
But not my first time here. I have used askubuntu a lot, the last few weeks and i have found answers to many questions i had.
Unfortunately since im a linux noob i can't provide any answers. Yet ;D
To the point.
I have installed 14.04 on a dell laptop with one onboard and one discrete nvidia gpu.
My problem is that i can't make ubuntu to "see" and use the nvidia gpu.
After reading around, i have done several things. 
I 've installed the drivers (correctly i think), i installed nvidia prime and prime indicator (cause i want to be able to choose which gpu is used when) but nothing.
I can't post images so i 'll try to describe my problems.

1 on the additional drivers tab, i get "no additional drivers"

2 when i run "nvidia-xconfig" i get "command not found"

3 when i run "lspci -vnn | grep -i vga" it lists only the intel onboard gpu

4 the prime-indicator has a dimmed entry saying: sh 1: glxinfo: not found

5 when i click open nvidia settings on the left column it has only 2 entries Application profiles and nvidia-settings configuration

6 running "prime-select nvidia" gives two errors. "alternatives not set up properly" and "nvidia mode can't be enabled"

7 running "prime-select query" just gives unknown

Any help is appreciated.

ps.

last week i had it working using prime but i had to uninstall and reinstall ubuntu, for disk space related reasons, and now i can't get it to work again and i can't remember what i dit to make it work the 1st time". :D

Answer (score 1):

Ok, solved it.
I purged everything (driver,nvidia-prime,bumblebee).
Then installed the latest nvidia drivers (as shown [here](http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2014/12/install-nvidia-340-65-ubuntu-1504/) and then installed nvidia-prime and prime indicator as shown [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/412452/getting-hybrid-graphics-to-work-nvidia-prime-gt650m) and [here](http://www.webupd8.org/2014/01/prime-indicator-lets-you-quickly-switch.html).

I had some problems after rebooting. The monitor was working on 800x600 and there was nothing i could do about it so i switched to the intel gpu which led me to a black screen that was displaying a bunch of stuff and then froze.

After hard reseting though everything was back to normal and working.
Now everything works as it should.

Hope the info helps someone else.

Answer (score 0):

Simply install [bumblebee](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Bumblebee) and [bbswitch](https://github.com/Bumblebee-Project/bbswitch). I get four times the performance with a 630M compared to HD 4000 graphics.

Uninstall whatever drivers for Nvidia that you installed apart from bumblebee. Follow that wiki.