# How to configure an application to always run with DRI_PRIME=1 set? Is there an other way besides terminal?

Tags: drivers, 16.04, radeon, hybrid-graphics, amd-graphics

I had followed the instructions posted by emk2203 ([My AMD Radeon graphic card is not working on 16.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/757586/my-amd-radeon-graphic-card-is-not-working-on-16-04?rq=1)) and now I could make the apps use my secondary AMD card
and it's work!  Look:

[Firefox running (http://demo.marpi.pl/exp/mecha/) experiment at 15fps](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2DsT7.png)

Now, runnig Firefox by Terminal with DRI_PRIME=1:

`DRI_PRIME=1 firefox`

[The same experiment running at 61fps](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BXdE2.png)

Thanks emk2203!

Now I need to know how configure the system to always runs the app with the DRI_PRIME=1 set.

Sorry for bad english. I'm brasilian.

Comment: Your question is, I believe, "How do I run FireFox with the `DRI_PRIME=1` variable enabled," correct?

Comment: Unfortunately Not... What I need is always open Firefox or another software with the DRI_PRIME=1 command already set. So I just will need double click its icon in the desktop.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnvironmentVariables) is a little light reading on environment variables for those sleepless nights, but to cut to the chase, I quote:

"A suitable file for environment variable settings that affect the system as a whole (rather than just a particular user) is /etc/environment.

This file is specifically meant for system-wide environment variable settings. It is not a script file, but rather consists of assignment expressions, one per line."

So... Inserting your assignment DRI_PRIME=1 into /etc/environment and then restarting should do what you're asking.

Comment: Not _exactly_ what OP was asking. It will run **everything** on AMD GPU. Please add info about this caveat.

Answer (score 2):

There is now a **PrefersNonDefaultGPU** [.desktop file key](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/desktop-entry-spec/latest/ar01s06.html). It was [merged](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/xdg/xdg-specs/-/merge_requests/13) into the spec on 2020-04-27 and GNOME has just received [the first implementation](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-shell/-/merge_requests/1226) 3 hours ago and you may be able to use it after gnome-shell version 3.37.1.

Comment: In practice it doesn't work at all and this topic summarizes why
https://github.com/ValveSoftware/steam-for-linux/issues/9940

Answer (score 1):

You can set an environment variable system-wide by setting it in `/etc/default/locale`.  This will set it for *all* users, so you want to be sure that's what you really want.  Keep in mind that local settings (such as in `.bashrc`) will override the system-wide setting.