# installing graphics drivers nVidia 310M on Lenovo V460

Tags: 14.04, drivers, nvidia, graphics, 64-bit

Installation of driver for nVidia 310M on Lenovo V460 just failed, I have tried [this](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nvidia-graphics-drivers-310/310.44-0ubuntu2).
I am kind of not very experienced linux user, so I don't actually understand what just happened. This was first message:

```
You do not appear to have an NVIDIA GPU supported by the 310.44     
NVIDIA Linux graphics driver installed in this system.  For further 
details, please see the appendix SUPPORTED NVIDIA GRAPHICS CHIPS in 
the README available on the Linux driver download page at           
www.nvidia.com.
```

But I am very sure that my PC have combined Nvidia/intel graphic card.
and installing nvidia-prime also haven't even showed up in dash.

and second:

```
ERROR: You appear to be running an X server; please exit X before            
installing.  For further details, please see the section INSTALLING   
THE NVIDIA DRIVER in the README available on the Linux driver         
download page at www.nvidia.com.
```

I was looking through quite a lot of questions, but I never know which tactics should I use.

I also tried going to "additional drivers" tab in "drivers" settings, but Ubuntu can't find my card.

P.S. I have i3 processor and I am running 64bit 14.04 ubuntu. If the solution on any other platform(maybe 32bit?) will be easier, I will gladly switch.

Comment: it will be easy if you install latest drivers from online source using command line. I have nvidia 820m on 14.04 using v346 driver smoothly

Comment: possible duplicate of [Getting hybrid graphics to work nvidia-prime GT650M](http://askubuntu.com/questions/412452/getting-hybrid-graphics-to-work-nvidia-prime-gt650m)

Comment: this doesn't work. I end on the first step of that solution. My PC can't find the video card on that "additional drivers" tab.

Answer (score 0):

According to [videocardbenchmark.net](http://www.videocardbenchmark.net/gpu.php?gpu=GeForce+310M&id=102) your nVidia 310M is just not up to par for modern OSes/applications any more.

Depending on the rest of your hardware, you should start looking to downgrade to Xubuntu/Lubuntu or upgrade your hardware...

*Sorry to be the harbinger of bad news...*