# Kubuntu 15.04 vivid - Nvidia GTX 660M (Optimus again)

Tags: drivers, nvidia, kubuntu, 15.04, nvidia-optimus

I'm really sorry that I pull this topic again but "I still haven't found what I'm looking for...".

I've tried tons of solutions with several behaviors, and I can't get it work properly.

First of all should I still use bumblebee at vivid or there is a working alternative as primus? I've tried primus and my kubuntu suddenly stopped working. I have average experience in Linux OS but I'm going to really love it. - Only this one thing making me so depressed.

I'm afraid that I have to reinstall kubuntu cause my installation steps for nvidia drivers went wrong way - but I'm ready to do this.

Please let me know what can I do and what should I do.

P.S.
Lenovo Y580
Nvidia GTX 660M
(Windows7 + Kubuntu)

Here is what I get:

```
[ 3017.144966] [DEBUG]Reading file: /etc/bumblebee/bumblebee.conf
[ 3017.145236] [DEBUG]optirun version 3.2.1 starting...
[ 3017.145253] [DEBUG]Active configuration:
[ 3017.145263] [DEBUG] bumblebeed config file: /etc/bumblebee/bumblebee.conf
[ 3017.145273] [DEBUG] X display: :8
[ 3017.145283] [DEBUG] LD_LIBRARY_PATH: 
[ 3017.145293] [DEBUG] Socket path: /var/run/bumblebee.socket
[ 3017.145302] [DEBUG] Accel/display bridge: auto
[ 3017.145309] [DEBUG] VGL Compression: proxy
[ 3017.145316] [DEBUG] VGLrun extra options: 
[ 3017.145324] [DEBUG] Primus LD Path: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/primus:/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/primus
[ 3017.145358] [DEBUG]Using auto-detected bridge primus
[ 3017.780263] [INFO]Response: No - error: [XORG] (EE) NOUVEAU(0): [drm] failed to set drm interface version.

[ 3017.780290] [ERROR]Cannot access secondary GPU - error: [XORG] (EE) NOUVEAU(0): [drm] failed to set drm interface version.

[ 3017.780301] [DEBUG]Socket closed.
[ 3017.780321] [ERROR]Aborting because fallback start is disabled.
[ 3017.780338] [DEBUG]Killing all remaining processes.
```

and

```
[ 2417.927428] [WARN][XORG] (WW) "glamoregl" will not be loaded unless you've specified it to be loaded elsewhere.
[ 2417.927472] [WARN][XORG] (WW) "xmir" is not to be loaded by default. Skipping.
[ 2417.927498] [ERROR][XORG] (EE) NOUVEAU(0): [drm] failed to set drm interface version.
[ 2417.927517] [ERROR][XORG] (EE) NOUVEAU(0): [drm] error opening the drm
[ 2417.927531] [ERROR][XORG] (EE) NOUVEAU(0): 1000: 
[ 2417.927545] [ERROR][XORG] (EE) Screen(s) found, but none have a usable configuration.
[ 2417.927560] [ERROR][XORG] (EE) 
[ 2417.927572] [ERROR][XORG] (EE) no screens found(EE) 
[ 2417.927584] [ERROR][XORG] (EE) 
[ 2417.927597] [ERROR][XORG] (EE) Please also check the log file at "/var/log/Xorg.8.log" for additional information.
[ 2417.927610] [ERROR][XORG] (EE) 
[ 2417.928055] [ERROR][XORG] (EE) Server terminated with error (1). Closing log file.
[ 2417.928068] [ERROR]X did not start properly
```

(I'm not sure why `[ 3017.145283] [DEBUG] LD_LIBRARY_PATH:` above is empty.)

bumblebee.conf file:

```
# Configuration file for Bumblebee. Values should **not** be put between quotes

## Server options. Any change made in this section will need a server restart
# to take effect.
[bumblebeed]
# The secondary Xorg server DISPLAY number
VirtualDisplay=:8
# Should the unused Xorg server be kept running? Set this to true if waiting
# for X to be ready is too long and don't need power management at all.
KeepUnusedXServer=false
# The name of the Bumbleblee server group name (GID name)
ServerGroup=bumblebee
# Card power state at exit. Set to false if the card shoud be ON when Bumblebee
# server exits.
TurnCardOffAtExit=false
# The default behavior of '-f' option on optirun. If set to "true", '-f' will
# be ignored.
NoEcoModeOverride=false
# The Driver used by Bumblebee server. If this value is not set (or empty),
# auto-detection is performed. The available drivers are nvidia and nouveau
# (See also the driver-specific sections below)
Driver=
# Directory with a dummy config file to pass as a -configdir to secondary X
XorgConfDir=/etc/bumblebee/xorg.conf.d

## Client options. Will take effect on the next optirun executed.
[optirun]
# Acceleration/ rendering bridge, possible values are auto, virtualgl and
# primus.
Bridge=auto
# The method used for VirtualGL to transport frames between X servers.
# Possible values are proxy, jpeg, rgb, xv and yuv.
VGLTransport=proxy
# List of paths which are searched for the primus libGL.so.1 when using
# the primus bridge
PrimusLibraryPath=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/primus:/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/primus
# Should the program run under optirun even if Bumblebee server or nvidia card
# is not available?
AllowFallbackToIGC=false


# Driver-specific settings are grouped under [driver-NAME]. The sections are
# parsed if the Driver setting in [bumblebeed] is set to NAME (or if auto-
# detection resolves to NAME).
# PMMethod: method to use for saving power by disabling the nvidia card, valid
# values are: auto - automatically detect which PM method to use
#         bbswitch - new in BB 3, recommended if available
#       switcheroo - vga_switcheroo method, use at your own risk
#             none - disable PM completely
# https://github.com/Bumblebee-Project/Bumblebee/wiki/Comparison-of-PM-methods

## Section with nvidia driver specific options, only parsed if Driver=nvidia
[driver-nvidia]
# Module name to load, defaults to Driver if empty or unset
KernelDriver=nvidia
PMMethod=auto
# colon-separated path to the nvidia libraries
LibraryPath=/usr/lib/nvidia-346:/usr/lib32/nvidia-346
# comma-separated path of the directory containing nvidia_drv.so and the
# default Xorg modules path
XorgModulePath=/usr/lib/nvidia-346/xorg,/usr/lib/xorg/modules
XorgConfFile=/etc/bumblebee/xorg.conf.nvidia-346

## Section with nouveau driver specific options, only parsed if Driver=nouveau
[driver-nouveau]
KernelDriver=nouveau
PMMethod=auto
XorgConfFile=/etc/bumblebee/xorg.conf.nouveau
```

and installed packages:

```
ii  bumblebee                                     3.2.1-7                                    amd64        NVIDIA Optimus support for Linux
ii  bumblebee-nvidia                              3.2.1-7                                    amd64        NVIDIA Optimus support using the proprietary NVIDIA driver
ii  nvidia-346                                    346.59-0ubuntu1                            amd64        NVIDIA binary driver - version 346.59
rc  nvidia-346-updates                            346.59-0ubuntu1                            amd64        NVIDIA binary driver - version 346.59
ii  nvidia-opencl-icd-346                         346.59-0ubuntu1                            amd64        NVIDIA OpenCL ICD
rc  nvidia-opencl-icd-346-updates                 346.59-0ubuntu1                            amd64        NVIDIA OpenCL ICD
ii  nvidia-prime                                  0.8.1                                      amd64        Tools to enable NVIDIA's Prime
ii  nvidia-settings                               346.59-0ubuntu1                            amd64        Tool for configuring the NVIDIA graphics driver
```

Answer (score 0):

I have the Lenovo Y580, and got the similar issue on Kubuntu 15.04. Bumblebee worked perfectly on Kubuntu 14.04 LTS. I have no choice but to revert back to 14.04.
Could you try removing the bumblebee and install only the nvidia prime. [Getting hybrid graphics to work nvidia-prime GT650M](https://askubuntu.com/questions/412452/getting-hybrid-graphics-to-work-nvidia-prime-gt650m)
I would like to know the result.  Thanks

Comment: I've tried this solution before you've posted. After a long time I can say it works. Not perfectly, because I still got unknown error before I log in (it stays at tty1), but everything displays properly and PC doesn't freeze. So it's acceptable, but I won't post it as solving answer. btw. thanks for response.