# Deciphering Nvidia-375 /var/log/syslog errors

Tags: 16.04, drivers, xorg, nvidia-optimus, nvidia-geforce

I'm hoping if I can figure out these nVidia error messages I can get it working properly:

```
Aug  6 09:25:25 dell com.ubuntu.ScreenResolution.Mechanism[1312]: update-alternatives: using /usr/lib/nvidia-375/ld.so.conf to provide /etc/ld.so.conf.d/x86_64-linux-gnu_GL.conf (x86_64-linux-gnu_gl_conf) in manual mode
Aug  6 09:25:25 dell com.ubuntu.ScreenResolution.Mechanism[1312]: /sbin/ldconfig.real: /usr/lib/nvidia-375/libEGL.so.1 is not a symbolic link
Aug  6 09:25:25 dell com.ubuntu.ScreenResolution.Mechanism[1312]: /sbin/ldconfig.real: /usr/lib32/nvidia-375/libEGL.so.1 is not a symbolic link
Aug  6 09:25:25 dell com.ubuntu.ScreenResolution.Mechanism[1312]: update-alternatives: using /usr/lib/nvidia-375/ld.so.conf to provide /etc/ld.so.conf.d/x86_64-linux-gnu_EGL.conf (x86_64-linux-gnu_egl_conf) in manual mode
Aug  6 09:25:25 dell com.ubuntu.ScreenResolution.Mechanism[1312]: /sbin/ldconfig.real: /usr/lib/nvidia-375/libEGL.so.1 is not a symbolic link
Aug  6 09:25:25 dell com.ubuntu.ScreenResolution.Mechanism[1312]: /sbin/ldconfig.real: /usr/lib32/nvidia-375/libEGL.so.1 is not a symbolic link
Aug  6 09:25:25 dell com.ubuntu.ScreenResolution.Mechanism[1312]: update-alternatives: using /usr/lib/nvidia-375/alt_ld.so.conf to provide /etc/ld.so.conf.d/i386-linux-gnu_GL.conf (i386-linux-gnu_gl_conf) in manual mode
Aug  6 09:25:25 dell com.ubuntu.ScreenResolution.Mechanism[1312]: /sbin/ldconfig.real: /usr/lib/nvidia-375/libEGL.so.1 is not a symbolic link
Aug  6 09:25:25 dell com.ubuntu.ScreenResolution.Mechanism[1312]: /sbin/ldconfig.real: /usr/lib32/nvidia-375/libEGL.so.1 is not a symbolic link
Aug  6 09:25:25 dell com.ubuntu.ScreenResolution.Mechanism[1312]: update-alternatives: using /usr/lib/nvidia-375/alt_ld.so.conf to provide /etc/ld.so.conf.d/i386-linux-gnu_EGL.conf (i386-linux-gnu_egl_conf) in manual mode
Aug  6 09:25:25 dell com.ubuntu.ScreenResolution.Mechanism[1312]: /sbin/ldconfig.real: /usr/lib/nvidia-375/libEGL.so.1 is not a symbolic link
Aug  6 09:25:25 dell com.ubuntu.ScreenResolution.Mechanism[1312]: /sbin/ldconfig.real: /usr/lib32/nvidia-375/libEGL.so.1 is not a symbolic link
Aug  6 09:25:25 dell com.ubuntu.ScreenResolution.Mechanism[1312]: Info: the current GL alternatives in use are: ['mesa', 'nvidia-375-prime']
Aug  6 09:25:25 dell com.ubuntu.ScreenResolution.Mechanism[1312]: Info: the current EGL alternatives in use are: ['mesa-egl', 'nvidia-375-prime']
Aug  6 09:25:25 dell com.ubuntu.ScreenResolution.Mechanism[1312]: Info: selecting nvidia-375 for the nvidia profile
Aug  6 09:26:10 dell systemd-udevd[433]: Process '/sbin/modprobe nvidia-modeset' failed with exit code 1.
Aug  6 09:26:10 dell systemd-udevd[433]: Process '/sbin/modprobe nvidia-drm' failed with exit code 1.
Aug  6 09:26:10 dell systemd-udevd[433]: Process '/sbin/modprobe nvidia-uvm' failed with exit code 1.
Aug  6 09:26:10 dell systemd-udevd[506]: failed to execute '/usr/bin/nvidia-smi' '/usr/bin/nvidia-smi': No such file or directory
Aug  6 09:26:10 dell systemd-udevd[433]: Process '/usr/bin/nvidia-smi' failed with exit code 2.
Aug  6 09:26:10 dell systemd[1139]: nvidia-persistenced.service: Failed at step EXEC spawning /usr/bin/nvidia-persistenced: No such file or directory
Aug  6 09:26:10 dell kernel: [    1.269533] nvidia: module license 'NVIDIA' taints kernel.
Aug  6 09:26:10 dell kernel: [    1.273379] nvidia: module verification failed: signature and/or required key missing - tainting kernel
Aug  6 09:26:10 dell kernel: [    1.279259] nvidia 0000:01:00.0: enabling device (0006 -> 0007)
Aug  6 09:26:10 dell kernel: [    1.279423] nvidia-nvlink: Nvlink Core is being initialized, major device number 247
Aug  6 09:26:10 dell kernel: [    1.280666] nvidia-modeset: Loading NVIDIA Kernel Mode Setting Driver for UNIX platforms  375.82  Wed Jul 19 20:35:11 PDT 2017
Aug  6 09:26:10 dell kernel: [    1.281343] [drm] [nvidia-drm] [GPU ID 0x00000100] Loading driver
Aug  6 09:26:10 dell gpu-manager[1106]: update-alternatives: using /usr/lib/nvidia-375/ld.so.conf to provide /etc/ld.so.conf.d/x86_64-linux-gnu_GL.conf (x86_64-linux-gnu_gl_conf) in manual mode
Aug  6 09:26:10 dell systemd[1]: nvidia-persistenced.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=203
Aug  6 09:26:10 dell systemd[1]: nvidia-persistenced.service: Unit entered failed state.
Aug  6 09:26:10 dell systemd[1]: nvidia-persistenced.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Aug  6 09:26:11 dell gpu-manager[1106]: /sbin/ldconfig.real: /usr/lib/nvidia-375/libEGL.so.1 is not a symbolic link
Aug  6 09:26:11 dell gpu-manager[1106]: /sbin/ldconfig.real: /usr/lib32/nvidia-375/libEGL.so.1 is not a symbolic link
Aug  6 09:26:11 dell gpu-manager[1106]: /sbin/ldconfig.real: /usr/lib/nvidia-375/libEGL.so.1 is not a symbolic link
Aug  6 09:26:11 dell gpu-manager[1106]: /sbin/ldconfig.real: /usr/lib32/nvidia-375/libEGL.so.1 is not a symbolic link
Aug  6 09:26:11 dell gpu-manager[1106]: update-alternatives: using /usr/lib/nvidia-375/ld.so.conf to provide /etc/ld.so.conf.d/x86_64-linux-gnu_EGL.conf (x86_64-linux-gnu_egl_conf) in manual mode
Aug  6 09:26:11 dell gpu-manager[1106]: /sbin/ldconfig.real: /usr/lib/nvidia-375/libEGL.so.1 is not a symbolic link
Aug  6 09:26:11 dell gpu-manager[1106]: /sbin/ldconfig.real: /usr/lib32/nvidia-375/libEGL.so.1 is not a symbolic link
Aug  6 09:26:11 dell gpu-manager[1106]: /sbin/ldconfig.real: /usr/lib/nvidia-375/libEGL.so.1 is not a symbolic link
Aug  6 09:26:11 dell gpu-manager[1106]: /sbin/ldconfig.real: /usr/lib32/nvidia-375/libEGL.so.1 is not a symbolic link
Aug  6 09:26:11 dell nvidia-persistenced: Verbose syslog connection opened
Aug  6 09:26:11 dell nvidia-persistenced: Now running with user ID 123 and group ID 133
Aug  6 09:26:11 dell nvidia-persistenced: Started (1580)
Aug  6 09:26:11 dell nvidia-persistenced: device 0000:01:00.0 - registered
Aug  6 09:26:11 dell nvidia-persistenced: Local RPC service initialized
Aug  6 09:26:11 dell kernel: [   15.479066] nvidia-modeset: Allocated GPU:0 (GPU-53117c49-1749-eec0-6033-9e00481807f5) @ PCI:0000:01:00.0
Aug  6 09:26:11 dell kernel: [   15.479687] nvidia-modeset: Freed GPU:0 (GPU-53117c49-1749-eec0-6033-9e00481807f5) @ PCI:0000:01:00.0
```

**NOTE:** I can confirm the above error message "Process '/usr/bin/nvidia-smi' failed with exit code 2" because I was trying to run it before this to see what information could be gleamed about the GPU.

### History

I used `prime-select nvidia` to turn on nVidia. Then it booted to black login screen. I updated grub kernel parameters with `nomodeset`:

- The external display (HDMI 1920x1080) disappeared
- The desktop icons piled up on top of each other at the bottom of display
- The brightness control slider disappeared

### Configuration

`apt list --installed | grep nvidia`:

```
nvidia-375/xenial,now 375.82-0ubuntu0~gpu16.04.1 amd64 [installed]
nvidia-opencl-icd-375/xenial,now 375.82-0ubuntu0~gpu16.04.1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
nvidia-prime/xenial,now 0.8.2 amd64 [installed]
nvidia-settings/xenial,now 384.59-0ubuntu0~gpu16.04.1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
```

`lspci | grep -E "VGA|3D`:

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller (rev 09)
```

**NOTE:** Nvidia geforce GT650M used to show up but it disappeared today after changing back from intel to nvidia and back to intel.

`cat /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/20-intel.conf`:

```
Section "Device"
   Identifier  "Intel Graphics"
   Driver      "intel"
   Option      "TearFree"    "true"
EndSection
```

**NOTE:** I tried to setup xorg.conf.new using:

`sudo Xorg :2 -configure`

```
X.Org X Server 1.18.4
Release Date: 2016-07-19
X Protocol Version 11, Revision 0
Build Operating System: Linux 4.4.0-83-generic x86_64 Ubuntu
Current Operating System: Linux dell 4.4.0-89-generic #112-Ubuntu SMP Mon Jul 31 19:38:41 UTC 2017 x86_64
Kernel command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-89-generic root=UUID=d02dc21d-dcb2-478e-9f7d-9a3331931de4 ro quiet splash vt.handoff=7 kaslr noht vt.handoff=7
Build Date: 17 July 2017  05:05:12PM
xorg-server 2:1.18.4-0ubuntu0.3 (For technical support please see http://www.ubuntu.com/support) 
Current version of pixman: 0.33.6
    Before reporting problems, check http://wiki.x.org
    to make sure that you have the latest version.
Markers: (--) probed, (**) from config file, (==) default setting,
    (++) from command line, (!!) notice, (II) informational,
    (WW) warning, (EE) error, (NI) not implemented, (??) unknown.
(==) Log file: "/var/log/Xorg.2.log", Time: Sun Aug  6 10:57:58 2017
List of video drivers:
    amdgpu
    ati
    cirrus
    intel
    mach64
    neomagic
    nouveau
    openchrome
    qxl
    r128
    radeon
    savage
    siliconmotion
    sisusb
    tdfx
    trident
    vmware
    fbdev
    vesa
    modesetting
    mga
(++) Using config file: "/home/Me/xorg.conf.new"
(==) Using config directory: "/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d"
(==) Using system config directory "/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d"


Xorg detected your mouse at device /dev/input/mice.
Please check your config if the mouse is still not
operational, as by default Xorg tries to autodetect
the protocol.

Your xorg.conf file is /home/Me/xorg.conf.new

To test the server, run 'X -config /home/rick/xorg.conf.new'

(EE) Server terminated with error (2). Closing log file.
```

The generated xorg config file doesn't have an nvidia sections though. Stopping lightdm service through console and running config there also terminates with error (2).

Comment: You might look at https://askubuntu.com/questions/412452/getting-hybrid-graphics-to-work-nvidia-prime-gt650m, and/or Google "ubuntu nvidia gt650m driver". It also seems like your kernel modules aren't getting built correctly.

Comment: @heynnema Good call on the kernel modules. I rebooted with kernel 4.4.0-78 and the `nvidia-smi` program is compiled there. This morning I had booted with the most recent 4.4.0-89 kernel but DKMS had not compiled the modules when Ubuntu Update ran yesterday or the day before. Unfortunately the links on the GT650M are all old and things have changed since then. Thanks for your kernel advice -- it gives me a fresh start to try things out and explains many problems I had today.